# Prevent NodeJS from exiting event-loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, exit, event-loop

Hey hava googled and tried every thing - but nothing seems to work, so now i will ask you guys:

How do i make my Node app. from stop exiting - when i like it to keep running and wait for response from a Web Socket connection?
As you can see i have tried different stuff in the 'PreventExit' function. I simply want the app. to keep receiving data from the web socket connection - without closing/exiting.

```
var Gdax = require('gdax');
var WSemitter = require('../eventemitters/websocket-emitter');

module.exports = {
    initws: function () {
        var WebSocketEmit = new WSemitter();

        test();

        function test() {
            try {
                PreventExit();

                var websocket = new Gdax.WebsocketClient();
                websocket.on('message', function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    WebSocketEmit.fakeEvent();
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        function PreventExit(){
            WebSocketEmit.on('fakeEvent', function () {
                console.log('Just fake - to keep node running!');
            });

            setTimeout(function(){}, 100000);
            process.stdin.resume();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1:**

My Web Socket provider CoinBase has recently updated their API. From Coinbase-exchange to Gdax. I just tried to replace:

```
var Gdax = require('gdax');
var CoinbaseExchange = require('coinbase-exchange');

//var websocket = new Gdax.WebsocketClient();
var websocket = new CoinbaseExchange.WebsocketClient();
```

and now my app waits! But after only 1 received json object my node app still exits!?? How do i make it keep the coonection open and not just shut down? But instead keeps receiving data from the API?

**Update 2**

When i remove all my test code and ONLY have the code related to the API, it works - BUT only with the old one...coinbase-exchange?? So it must be an error in there new (gdax)API or what? But no exception is thrown??

**Please see the doc here:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/coinbase-exchange#websocket-client

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gdax#websocket-client

Further the DOC states (Which makes no sense - when it is only the old API which is the one still working):

GDAX transition
As part of the rebranding of Coinbase Exchange to GDAX, API endpoints have changed. The old *.exchange.coinbase.com endpoints will continue working until Aug 24th, 2016. For the new endpoints see the documentation below.

Comment: did you call initws somewhere?

Comment: Yes - i initws() is called from my server.js file ... which i start from the CMD by 'node server'

Comment: Unless I have missed something, you're not waiting for connections anywhere in your code. If you did, node would not exit.

Comment: websocket.on is waiting for response...

Answer (score 2):

### Using setTimeout

You can do something like this - create a timeout that re-registers itself:

```
var t;
function nt() {
  t = setTimeout(nt, 10000);
}
nt();
```

Every time you can turn it off by calling `clearTimeout`. For example to make your program exit after 2 seconds you can add:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  clearTimeout(t);
}, 2000);
```

So it doesn't even have to wait for those full 10 seconds (or whatever is the interval) to finish.

### Using setInterval

You can make it even simpler with `setInterval`:

```
var i = setInterval(()=>{}, 10000);
```

And you can cancel it with `clearInterval`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  clearInterval(i);
}, 2000);
```

### Real problem

**But** if your process exits then there's a good chance that **it does so because it no longer waits for anything to happen** and that's the real problem. So keeping Node from exiting may not fix your problem in that case - **it will just wait for nothing to happen**.

Comment: I have already tried with an setInterval function... in my PreventExit function... but it doesnt change any thing at all... all this seems to do the same - nothing...?

Comment: `setInterval` solution works just great, the only thing is that I enclose the code into `if(1){...}` in Node REPL - another lifehack found here.